# Eliminar Objeto de un TreeSet java

Tags: java

estoy haciendo un ejercicio de clase. Estoy creando un método para poder borrar un objeto según el atributo que pasemos por teclado. En esta ocasión tengo que eliminar un vehiculo metiendo la matricula. Ejercicio especifica que la colección debe ser un TreeSet. La cosa es que como lo tengo, me borra todo, lo que quiero hacer es que me elimina la matricula que le paso. No tengo cojones a hacerlo, ¿me podéis echar una mano?

Tengo esto:

```
public void eliminarVehiculo(String matricula) {
    Iterator<Vehiculo> iter = agencia.iterator();

    while (iter.hasNext()) {
        String resultado = iter.next().getMatricula();
        Vehiculo vehiculo = (Vehiculo) iter.next();
        if (vehiculo.getMatricula()==resultado.equals(matricula)){
        } else {
            agencia.remove(vehiculo);
        }



    }
}
```

Comment: Pues te falta revisar en la revisión del item, comparando la matrícula que recibes con la matrícula del vehículo en la iteración.

Comment: Como haría eso? he estado buscando por internet, pero no he encontrado nada...

Comment: Pues no conocemos cómo es la clase Vehículo, pero esta tendrá una matrícula, suponemos. Dentro del ciclo while haces la comparación con la matrícula y, si son iguales, haces el `remove`. No hace falta buscar en Internet

Comment: Lo he modificado, pero me da error en el if. Puedes ponerme un ejemplo?

Comment: la comparación entre strings no se hace con el operador `==`, sino que usa equals. Busca la forma correcta de usar equals con dos String y modifícalo. Y si estás poniendo la matrícula del vehículo en la iteración dentro de un string, no tendríás por qué volverlo a obtener en la validación del if. De paso, no tiene sentido hacer la eliminación en el else si la condición que buscas es que sí sea igual (o sea, en el bloque if). PD. Con gusto te guiamos pero en SO no se escribe el código de los demás :)

Comment: Y no hay que hacer dos *.next()* dentro de cada iteración, ya que cada vez que haces *.next()* obtienes el siguiente elemento de la lista.

Answer (score -1):

```java
    public void eliminarVehiculo(String matricula){

    Iterator<Vehiculo> iter = agencia.iterator();
    while (iter.hasNext()) {
        
        Vehiculo vehiculo = (Vehiculo) iter.next();
        if (vehiculo.getMatricula().equals(matricula)){
            agencia.remove(vehiculo);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Te recomiendo leer [answer] y hacer el [tour] (de paso te sacas un par de medallas) para entender cómo funciona SO y cómo elaborar una respuesta **correctamente**. Porque si, esta respuesta puede que sea correcta, pero no está correctamente construida puesto que solo es código sin ninguna explicación ni indicio que le indique a los usuarios con dudas qué hace, cómo lo hace o por qué lo hace. Si quien hizo la pregunta supiese esto, no haría falta ponérselo, pero como no lo sabe, mejor explicarlo, no crees? :) Por favor usa el botón [edit] y añade una explicación!